# How can I solve VPN Connection Error in C#

Tags: c#, vpn

I use a VPN class in my program. But when I try to connect, it cause the following error:

> the system could not find the phone book entry for this connection

Here is the connect method:

```
public void VPN_Connect(string VPN_Name, string VPN_ID, string VPN_PW)
{
    string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk";
    AllUsersPhoneBook = new RasPhoneBook();
    AllUsersPhoneBook.Open(path);

    if (AllUsersPhoneBook.Entries.Contains(EntryName))
    {
        AllUsersPhoneBook.Entries[EntryName].PhoneNumber = VPN_Name;
        AllUsersPhoneBook.Entries[EntryName].Update();
    }
    else
    {
        RasEntry entry = RasEntry.CreateVpnEntry(EntryName, VPN_Name, RasVpnStrategy.Default,
                        RasDevice.GetDeviceByName("(PPTP)", RasDeviceType.Vpn));

        entry.EncryptionType = RasEncryptionType.None;

        AllUsersPhoneBook.Entries.Add(entry);
    }

    Dialer = new RasDialer();
    Dialer.DialCompleted += new EventHandler<DialCompletedEventArgs>(Dialer_DialCompleted);

    this.Dialer.EntryName = EntryName;
    this.Dialer.PhoneBookPath = RasPhoneBook.GetPhoneBookPath(RasPhoneBookType.AllUsers);

    try
    {
        this.Dialer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(VPN_ID, VPN_PW);
        this.handle = this.Dialer.DialAsync();
        VPN_Status = (int)status.Defalut;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

I'm also using windows 10 with latest update and DotRas last version.

Comment: That looks like a Networking problem or a problem working with this Library. It seems unlikely this falls under C#. Also as you are exposing teh Full Exception detail, it would help a lot to tell them to us. Particular the Exception Class. The Stack Trace might help too.

Comment: Umh if you are targeting windows 10 may I suggest using [windows.networking.vpn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.vpn). It nicely covers up the details for you. Only drawback is you would need to add a manifest file and run your app inside a container so actually I can't really recommend.